# Problem with emails from Webform

Tags: 7, webforms, emails

I have problems with incoming emails. Which are sent from the module webform (and use SMTP Module)

Mail destination are those with "domain.com". I reported receiving a first email with all the data readable. But there comes a second email with the following:

```
op: insert, sid: 4, components: nombre: value: REMOVED,
component: nid: 17, cid: 1, pid: 0, form_key: nombre, name: Nombre, type:
textfield, value: , extra: title_display: inline, private: 0, disabled: 0,
unique: 0, conditional_operator: =, width: , maxlength: , field_prefix: ,
field_suffix: , description: , attributes: , conditional_component: ,
conditional_values: , mandatory: 1, weight: 0, page_num: 1, empresa: value:
inClouds Group, component: nid: 17, cid: 2, pid: 0, form_key: empresa, name:
Empresa, type: textfield, value: , extra: title_display: inline, private: 0,
disabled: 0, unique: 0, conditional_operator: =, width: , maxlength: ,
field_prefix: , field_suffix: , description: , attributes: ,
conditional_component: , conditional_values: , mandatory: 1, weight: 1,
page_num: 1, e_mail: value: user@domain.com, component: nid: 17,
cid: 3, pid: 0, form_key: e_mail, name: E-mail, type: email, value: , extra:
title_display: inline, private: 0, disabled: 0, unique: 0,
conditional_operator: =, width: , description: , attributes: ,
conditional_component: , conditional_values: , mandatory: 1, weight: 2,
page_num: 1, tipo_de_requerimiento: value: user@domain.com, component:
nid: 17, cid: 4, pid: 6, form_key: tipo_de_requerimiento, name: Tipo de requerimiento, type: select, value: , extra: items:
user@domain.com,user@domain.com|Servicios
user@domain.com,user@domain.com,user@domain.com|Integración
user@domain.com|Componentes
user@domain.com|Otros, multiple: 0, title_display: before, private:
0, aslist: 1, optrand: 0, conditional_operator: =, other_option: null,
other_text: Other..., description: , custom_keys: false, options_source: ,
conditional_component: , conditional_values: , mandatory: 1, weight: 4,
page_num: 1, contenido: value: ola k ace, component: nid: 17, cid: 5, pid: 0,
form_key: contenido, name: Contenido, type: textarea, value: , extra:
title_display: 0, private: 0, resizable: 0, disabled: 0,
conditional_operator: =, cols: , rows: , description: , attributes: ,
conditional_component: , conditional_values: , mandatory: 1, weight: 5,
page_num: 1
```

I have in my contact form component "Select / Option".
Which is formed in the following manner:

```
user@domain.com, user@domain.com | Area 1
user@domain.com, user@domain.com | Area 2
user@domain.com | Area 3
```

I do this because there are 3 areas and certain emails should go to different recipients.

Why this would be happening? Is module problem? Or is the problem of emails recipients?

Comment: What have you done to debug this?  What is the problem with the second e-mail-- that the formatting is messed up, or that it shouldn't be sent at all?

Comment: @PatrickKenny The debug is OK. The problem is that my client considered that the second email is a issue.
When I debug the email (using SMTP module) with some gmail account as a target, the email is OK (No send the second mail with that params).

Comment: I don't know why the second email show all values with their keys, nid, sid..